# function displaying as undefined

Tags: function, xhtml, calculator

My function should be returning a number, but it keeps returning "undefined,"  I've been through my textbook and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  I'm not sure if I'm defining my variables correctly, but I'm stuck and any direction would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Greendale Community College</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */
    var creditTotal = document.getElementsByName("numCredits");
    var tuitionCost = 0;
    function calcTuition() {
        tuitionCost = 302 * creditTotal;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><center><font face="impact" font size="200" color="green">Greendale Community College</font></center></p>
    <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256"/></center>
    <h1><center>Tuition Calculator</center></h1>
    <form name="tuitionCalculator" action="" method="get">
    <h2>Semester</h2>
    <h3>(choose a semester)</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="semesterFall"/> Fall 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSpring"/> Spring 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSummer"/> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h2>Residency</h2>
    <h3>(choose your residency)</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="instate" /> In-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="outstate" /> Out-of-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="international" /> International <br />
    <h2>Credits</h2>
    <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="numCredits" /><br />
            <input type="button" onclick="window.alert(calcTuition())" value="Calculate Your Tuition" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Functions typically have a `return` statement. Yours returns nothing (it simply assigns a value to a global variable), so you're getting `undefined`. You either want to actually return a value, or move your alert into the function and display `tuitionCost` instead.

Comment: If this were real XHTML, the CDATA section would be all wrong. You would need <![CDATA[ before the content of the script and ]]> after. However, this is a HTML file, even though the content looks like XHTML, so you actually don't need a CDATA section at all.

Comment: Some more comments: 1) the radio buttons should be grouped together by giving them the same `name` per group. Otherwise the user cannot select only one per group. 2) Elements like <center> and <font> were deprecated 18 years ago. 3) If you want to use <center>, put the <p> in the <center> rather than the other way around, which won't work. Also, take note that size="200" is awfully large.

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.getElementsByName("numCredits")` is a collection of all elements that have tagName `numCredits`. You need to use `[0]` to specify the top one.
2. `document.getElementsByName("numCredits")[0].value` is the one to give you the value of the input. Then don't forget to `parseInt` it to an integer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Greendale Community College</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */
    
    function calcTuition() {
      var tuitionCost = 0;
        var creditTotal = document.getElementsByName("numCredits")[0].value;
       console.log(creditTotal);
        tuitionCost = 302 * parseInt(creditTotal);
      return tuitionCost;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><center><font face="impact" font size="200" color="green">Greendale Community College</font></center></p>
    <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256"/></center>
    <h1><center>Tuition Calculator</center></h1>
    <form name="tuitionCalculator" action="" method="get">
    <h2>Semester</h2>
    <h3>(choose a semester)</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="semesterFall"/> Fall 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSpring"/> Spring 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSummer"/> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h2>Residency</h2>
    <h3>(choose your residency)</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="instate" /> In-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="outstate" /> Out-of-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="international" /> International <br />
    <h2>Credits</h2>
    <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="numCredits" /><br />
            <input type="button" onclick="window.alert(calcTuition())" value="Calculate Your Tuition" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```